# How to save and restore current page in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Good day!

I use ag-grid to show long list (with multiple pages) in 'infinite' row model with enabled paging. User can jump page to page. At some point user can click on row to view details. When he press back i want to restore UI state. I already implement restore for sorting and filtering. But can't find how to do it for paging. In other words i need to specify current page when ag-grid is created. I call 'paginationGoToPage' method in 'mounted' callback, in handler of 'onGridReady' event. No luck. ag-grid always start from first page. Please advise

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the api method `paginationGetCurrentPage` to get the current page. By leveraging the Grid Event `paginationChanged`, you can listen to when the user navigates to a new page and store the current page:

```
  onPaginationChanged: (params) => {
    if (params.newPage) {
      let currentPage = params.api.paginationGetCurrentPage();

      localStorage.setItem('currentPage', JSON.stringify(currentPage));
    }
  },
```

To restore the current page, simply do this via the api method `paginationGoToPage`:

```
  onFirstDataRendered: (params) => {
    const pageToNavigate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentPage'));
    params.api.paginationGoToPage(pageToNavigate);
  },
```

See this implemented in the following plunkr sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/RkOHpZ4bRhbWhY7D

Relevant Documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-pagination/#pagination-api

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seems paginationGoToPage doesn't work from onFirstDataRendered. It doesnt work even in sample from ag-grid.com. I fix it on my side by wrapping call of paginationGoToPage to setTimeout.

Comment: If paginationGoToPage does not work inside onFirstDataRendered from the documentation sample, I'd suggest raising this in the ag-grid github page as a possible bug so the team can investigate.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `paginationGoToPage()` api, it is really hard to find out as I was thinking it should be something like `SetPaginationxxx`.

Comment: The `params.newPage` flag is also Super handy! Thanks!

Comment: There is something like `setPagination` in aggrid but i don't know how to use it. @LeOn-HanLi

Refer link: 
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#pagination-api